# Save List of numbers in domain model error?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am currently trying to save a List of numbers associated to a domain model in Grails and I keep getting errors. So the scenario is:

I have a Client Domain Model that is shown below and this has a HasMany relationship with a PhoneNumbers Domain model that is also shown below. There is a view where a bunch of numbers are added and then these are stored in a String [] for processing on the controller.

**Client Domain:**

```
class Client {

    String name

    List numbers = new ArrayList()

    //This represents a message belonging to a single department
    static hasMany = [numbers:PhoneNumbers]

    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false)
    }


}
```

**Phone Numbers Domain:**

```
class PhoneNumbers {

    String number

    //This represents a message belonging to a single department
    static belongsTo = [client:Client]

    static constraints = {
        number(blank:false)
    }


}
```

As you can see the Client hasMany Phone Numbers and the Phone Numbers belongTo a Client. So in my controller I presumed all's I would need to do is to pass these numbers to the Domain in an Array or List and it would handle the cascade save, my controller function is below:

```
//This is an array of phone numbers stored in a sesson object as String []
        def numbers = session.getAttribute("phoneNumbers")

        def numbersConvert = numbers as List

        def client = new Client(numbers: numbersConvert, name: params.name)

        if (!client.save()) {
            client.errors.each{
                println(it)
            }
        }
```

so the controller above I would expect to take the array of numbers which I have confirmed has values and then convert that to a List. Then save the new Client data and cascade save all the numbers that that client has in the List. However this does not work and I get the error below:

```
GRAILS-7799: Subtype 'java.lang.String' of reloadable type com.tool.PhoneNumbers is not reloadable: may not see changes reloaded in this hierarchy (please comment on that jira)
| Error 2013-07-30 07:56:50,831 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR property.BasicPropertyAccessor  - IllegalArgumentException in class: com.smstool.PhoneNumbers, getter method of property: id
| Error 2013-07-30 07:56:50,836 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing 
object is not an instance of declaring class. Stacktrace follows:
Message: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

I did also try another approach to the save the data within the controller as shown below however this did not work either:

```
numbers.each{

            def phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber(number: it).save(flush: true)

            client.addToPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).save(flush: true)

        }
```

I presume I am missing something silly and this is probably a really easy thing to do just so tired and need a little help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `client.addToNumbers(phoneNumber)` instead of `addToPhoneNumber`

Comment: I have now solved this issue thanks